# Codeigniter Edit only own profile as user

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a problem that i can edit all profiles as user. but i want, that i only can edit my profile. Maybe you can help me. The code is working if i want to edit my profile like

domain/member/users/manage/1

but i can edit /member/users/manage/2 too and thats the problem.

Controller Users.php

```
public function manage($id = NULL) {

        if($this->session->userdata('type') == 'user') {

        $data = array();

        if ($id) {
            $this->{$this->model}->{$this->_primary_key} = $id;
            $data['item'] = $this->{$this->model}->get();
            if (!$data['item'])
                show_404();
        } else {
            $data['item'] = new Std();
        }


        $this->load->library("form_validation");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');

        $this->{$this->model}->custom_select = 'users.*, teams.title as teams';
        $this->{$this->model}->joins = array( 'teams' => array('teams.teams_id = users.teams_id', 'inner'));

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'firstname', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'lastname', 'trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('sex', 'sex', 'trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("image3", 'image3', "trim|callback_image3[$id]");

        $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", 'Email', "trim|required|valid_email");
        if ($id)
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim');
        else
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim');


        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            $this->load->view($this->module . '/manage', $data);

        else {
            $this->users_model->username = $this->input->post('username');
            $this->users_model->email = $this->input->post('email');

            $this->users_model->firstname = $this->input->post('firstname');
            $this->users_model->lastname = $this->input->post('lastname');
            $this->users_model->sex = $this->input->post('sex');

            if (strlen($this->input->post('password')) > 0)
                $this->{$this->model}->password = md5($this->input->post('password'));

            $this->{$this->model}->save();
            redirect('member/' . $this->module);
        }

        }else{
            exit('Hacking Attempt: Get out of the system ..!');
        }

    }
```

Users_model.php

```
<?php

class Users_model extends CI_model
{
    public $_table = 'users';
    public $_primary_keys = array('user_id');


}
```

Comment: Make role into session and check if (role==user) than redirect to other page or give message that you cant edit this details.

Comment: MD5 is considered broken for security purposes and is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.5, you can use [this compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First One you Must pass The user_id in session

Then Need `domain/member/users/manage/1`

You redirect to ur profile ...

If Users controller having function manage

```
class Users extends CI_Controller
{
  public function manage($userid)
  {
   #checking the with session value
   if(($this->session->userdata('user_id')!=$userid)):
      #if not satisfied means redirect another page
      redirect("Another page");
   endif;
  }
}
```